# override resolution behavior in c#

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I tried the following piece of code

```
public abstract class Entry3
{
    public abstract void Method1();
    public virtual void Method2() { Console.WriteLine("Entry3.Method2"); }
}

public abstract class Entry31 : Entry3
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entry31.Method1");
    }
    public virtual void Method2() { Console.WriteLine("Entry31.Method2"); }
}

public class Entry32 : Entry31
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
    public override void Method2() { Console.WriteLine("Entry32.Method2"); }
}

public class Main4
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Entry32 e32 = new Entry32();
        e32.Method1();

        //((Entry31)e32).Method1();
        ((Entry3)e32).Method1();

        e32.Method2();
        ((Entry31)e32).Method2();
        ((Entry3)e32).Method2();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The response was "Entry3.Method2" for the last line `((Entry3)e32).Method2();`. I have overridden the base `Entry31` Method2 in Entry32. Is C# finding that the `Entry3` Method2 not being overridden in Entry32 and calling Entry3.Method2. Can anyone help me understand this behavior

Comment: The behavior is different for virtual and abstract. I am a bit shaky in this difference in understanding

Comment: You should have gotten a warning when you compiled this code that explained the problem; did you ignore the warning?  Compiler warnings are there to tell you that your program is **probably wrong**, and *where* it is probably wrong; read them!

Comment: I missed it. Will note it from now on. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entry32::Method2` overrides `Entry31::Method2`, not `Entry3::Method2`. Since the override chain is broken between `Entry3` and `Entry31` (it is a shadow - completely different functions as far as the runtime is concerned) the virtual dispatch doesn't pass there.

Comment: Great, just now figured out with the sample code i have written here: https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=305&action=edit&message=6&postpost=v2